# Deleting INI section using Powershell and kernel32.dll

Tags: powershell, ini, kernel32

I am having trouble deleting a INI file section using Powershell.  I am calling WritePrivateProfileString in kernel32.dll with empty strings for the key and value.  Here's an example of the "before" ini:

```
[Section1]
Setting1=Value1
[Section2]
Setting2=Value2
```

Now I call WritePrivateProfileString, using an imported kernel32.dll (full code below):

```
$Kernel32::WritePrivateProfileString("Section2", "", "", "MyIniFile.ini")
```

I would expect this to delete Section2, but instead I get this:

```
[Section1]
Setting1=Value1
[Section2]
Setting2=Value2
=
```

So apparently the empty strings are not getting recognized as such by the underlying code.  Possibly a difference in the definition of an empty string?  Any help would be appreciated.  Here's the code that defines $Kernel32:

```
$Signature = @’ 
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")] 
public static extern bool WritePrivateProfileString(
    string lpAppName, 
    string lpKeyName, 
    string lpString, 
    string lpFileName); 
‘@ 

$Kernel32 = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $Signature -Name Win32Utils -Namespace WritePrivateProfileString -Using System.Text -PassThru 
$Kernel32::WritePrivateProfileString($Section, $Key, $Value, $File)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `[NullString]::Value`. Source: [Possible to pass null from Powershell to a .Net API that expects a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002570/possible-to-pass-null-from-powershell-to-a-net-api-that-expects-a-string)

Example:

```powershell
$Kernel32::WritePrivateProfileString("Section2", [NullString]::Value, [NullString]::Value, "MyIniFile.ini")
```