# Can strings be null in Powershell?

Tags: string, powershell, null

Why, in this powershell code, does the last statement resolve to true?

```
PS C:\> $s = [System.String]$null
PS C:\> $s.GetType()
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                  
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                  
True     True     String                                   System.Object 
PS C:\> $s -eq ""
True
```

Comment: `$s=[System.String][NullString]::Value`

Comment: Yes, or even `[System.String]$s=[System.String][NullString]::Value`. The meaning of the [variable `$null`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx) is NULL ___or___ an empty value. Somewhat related to [Possible to pass null from Powershell to a .Net API that expects a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002570/)

Comment: [related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45720150/1404637)

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell always converts null strings to empty string
Check accepted answer here for details : [Passing null to a mandatory parameter to a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25459799/passing-null-to-a-mandatory-parameter-to-a-function)

Comment: Sure, but the details there don't go into the question of why. It would be nice to understand the motivation here.

Answer (score 1):

Basically so you never have to write string.IsNullOrEmpty() or get a null reference on a string in PowerShell. See Tony Hoare "Null References: The Billion Dollar Mistake".