# Why does [NullString]::Value evaluate differently with a breakpoint?

Tags: powershell, debugging, breakpoints, null-string

I've tried this code in PowerShell ISE and VS Code with the same strange result.  Without a breakpoint, the output is `EMPTY`, but with a breakpoint in the line with `"NULL"`, the output is `NULL` (as expected).  Why?

```
function demo {
    param(
        [string] $value = [NullString]::Value
    )

    if ($null -eq $value) {
        "NULL"
    } elseif ($value -eq '') {
        "EMPTY"
    } else {
        "$value"
    }
}

demo
```

I know now, that PowerShell will always convert a non-string value (e.g. $null or [NullString]::Value) to an (empty) string, when you use the type modifier [string] for a parameter.
Fine, I can live with that, but it's hard to figure that out by yourself, if debugging is so weird in this case.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45720150/how-can-i-prevent-a-string-argument-changing-from-null-to-empty-when-bound-to-a I think this is already answered here. Initially found here: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4616

Comment: @mjsqu: That's good information that is definitely _related_, but this question is specifically about a discrepancy between the behavior during regular execution vs. debugging. It is the _debugging_ behavior that is more in line with the linked information.

Comment: Underlying cause probably (IMHO, very likely) related to https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4312 because if you put `if(0){rv}` inside `demo` or call `demo` without creating new scope, then it return correct result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003407/petseral), as many times before, has provided the crucial pointer in a comment on the question:

**A [known optimization bug](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4312) is the most likely cause** (as of Windows PowerShell v5.1 / PowerShell Core v6.1.0), and that bug just happens to be *masked* when the code is run in the Visual Studio Code or ISE *debugger*.

You can therefore use the same **workaround** mentioned in the linked bug report: place a call to `Remove-Variable` anywhere in the function body (its *presence* is enough - the call needn't actually be made at runtime):

```
function demo {
    param(
        [string] $value = [NullString]::Value
    )

    # Workaround for optimization bug
    if ($False) { Remove-Variable }

    if ($null -eq $value) {
        "NULL"
    } elseif ($value -eq '') {
        "EMPTY"
    } else {
        "$value"
    }
}

demo
```

Now you consistently get `"NULL"` as the output, whether debugging or not.

**However, it's best to restrict use of `[NullString]::Value` to what it was designed for: passing `null` to `string`-typed parameters of *.NET methods*** - see below.

---

As for **why use of `[NullString]::Value` is needed at all in order to pass `$null` to a string parameter / store `$null` in a `[string]` variable**, given that .NET strings can normally store `null` (`$null`) directly:

By (historical) design, PowerShell converts `$null` to `''` (the empty string) when you assign it to a `[string]` variable; here's the rationale:

From https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4616#issuecomment-323530442:

> The thinking behind the design was that in most ways, `$null` and the empty string both represent the same error condition and that in the rare case where a distinction was important, `$PSBoundParameters` would be sufficient to distinguish between knowing a value was provided or not.

Given that [even passing `$null` *directly* performs conversion to `''` when passing arguments to `string`-typed *.NET methods*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38958377/45375), you couldn't pass `null` to such methods up to v2.
To remedy that, version 3 introduced `[NullString]::Value`, which explicitly signals the desire to pass `$null` in a string context.
(The alternative - making PowerShell strings default to `$null` and allowing direct assignment of `$null` - was considered a change that would break too many existing scripts.)

**Using  `[NullString]::Value` beyond its intended purpose - i.e., for passing `null` to `string` parameters in .NET methods - is problematic, given that PowerShell doesn't expect `[string]` variables to contain `$null` in other contexts.**

Fixing the above-mentioned optimization bug would help in the scenario in the question, but there may be other pitfalls.

Answer (score 0):

> Difference between $null and ""
>
> Empty string is not the same as null; you'd need to test specifically
>   for that. Null is the non-existence of an object,  Whereas a string is
>   an object even if it's empty.
>
> That's a common gotcha in PowerShell. For whatever reason, it won't
>   let you assign a $null value to a string variable (or a string
>   parameter to a .NET type); it gets converted to an empty string. This
>   can cause some headaches when calling .NET methods that treat null and
>   empty strings differently, which is why they later added (in v3, if I
>   remember correctly), the [System.Management.Automation.NullString]
>   class. If you want to call such a method, you do this:
>
> [SomeClass]::SomeMethod([nullstring]::Value)
>
> [string]$camp = $null
>
> Will assign $Null to $Camp, but since the [string]-part forces $camp
>   to be of the type string, $Camp will be assigned the value of
>   [String]$Null
>
> [String]$Null will force a conversion of $Null (which is basically a
>   non-existing object) to a string and in PowerShell that results in an
>   empty string.
>
> As far as PowerShell is concerned, that's basically correct. However,
>   in the .NET Framework, strings really can be null, and there's a
>   difference between a null string reference and an empty string.
>   Sometimes that causes confusion when you're looking at .NET
>   documentation and wondering why it doesn't seem to work properly from
>   PowerShell.
>
> Use [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($variable)
>
> https://powershell.org/forums/topic/difference-between-null-and/

See also...

> How can I check if a string is null or empty in PowerShell?
>   [string]::IsNullOrEmpty(...)
>
> [How can I check if a string is null or empty in PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13738634/how-can-i-check-if-a-string-is-null-or-empty-in-powershell)

*** Update ***

Changing your code to this...

```
function demo {
    param(
        [string]$value
    )

    if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($value))
    {
        "NULL"
    } elseif ($value -eq '') {
        "EMPTY"
    } else {
        "$value"
    }
}
```

With or without debug (breakpoint set on 'NULL' and 'EMPTY') effort, the results returned are the same on my system ISE/VSCode

```
# Results 

demo
NULL

demo -value ''
NULL

demo -value ' '


demo -value test
test
```

*** Modification to show the elseif handling whitespace ***

With or with the conditions previously stated

```
 function demo {
    param(
        [string]$value
    )

    if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($value))
    {
        "NULL"
    } elseif ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($value)) {
        "EMPTY or a White Space"
    } else {
        "$value"
    }
}

# Results

demo
NULL
demo -value ''
NULL
demo -value ' '
EMPTY or a White Space
demo -value test
test
```

Comment: thank you, but I know all that, the point is the debugging mystery

Comment: BTW: Why you have to use [nullstring]::Value instead of $null for a .NET method expecting a string ?